# Hello, I am trying to use find Meeting Times API and I am facing the same issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am facing InvalidUserAddress and unsupportedScenario even thought I have checked the headers and params, 
Everything is correct,

I tried it with and without Location Constraint, Even Authorization token was perfect

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 80c3e650-3a57-49b5-b49d-39a4f585192e
client-request-id: 80c3e650-3a57-49b5-b49d-39a4f585192e
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South India","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_6","ADSiteName":"INS"}}
Duration: 78.1616
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2019 12:05:22 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Invalid user address",
    "innerError": {
      "code": "UnsupportedScenario",
      "request-id": "80c3e650-3a57-49b5-b49d-39a4f585192e",
      "date": "2019-02-08T12:05:23"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be usefull to add the url you’re trying and a link to the documentation you’re trying to use.

Comment: If you can provide this, i'm guessing that the list of user UPNs you put in attendees are incorrect. Please check the examples in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the same error when I try the v1.0 or beta version of the Graph findMeetingTimes method  (docs = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http ).

I'm using a registered app and thus Application permissions.  Sadly, that permission type is not supported for this method.

Is it possible, Siddhant, that you are using Application access, too?  If so, the only workaround seems to be using a login of the user or a user delegated access to an appropriate mailbox.